# Do tuples in python always have the property that `hash(x) == hash(y)` if and only if `x == y`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

Suppose that `tuppy` and `guppy` are:

- both instantiated from the `tuple` class
- the only elements of `tuppy` and `guppy` are integers such as `0`, `1`, `2`, etc...

Is it the case that `hash(tuppy) == hash(guppy)` if and only if `tuppy == guppy`?

Note that the following all amount to nearly the same thing:

```py
number = hash(t)
number = t.__hash__()
number = tuple.__hash__(t)
```

Will `hash(x) == hash(y)` always return `True` for examples like the following?

```py
x = tuple([0, 1])

y = tuple(range(0, 2))

print("x == ".ljust(20), type(x), repr(x))
print("y == ".ljust(20), type(y), repr(y))
print("hash(x) == hash(y)".ljust(20), hash(x) == hash(y))
```

I have two concerns:

- two different tuples hashing to the same value. For example `(1234, 5)` and `(1, 2345)` might, theoretically, both hash to the same value.
- `hash(copy.copy(x))` might be different than `hash(x)`.
- Do tuples have the behavior that `hash(x) == hash(y)` if and only if `x == y`, provided that:

  - the instances of `tuple` come directly from `tuple` and are not instantiated from a sub-class of `tuple`?
  - the elements of the `tuple` are integers?

The above assumes that we are working with tuples of integers.

What about nested trees of tuples?

```py
import copy

t1a = (1, (2, (3, (4, 5), 6)))
t1b = tuple(eval("[1, (2, (3, (4, 5), 6))]"))

t2a = ((((1, 2), 3), 4), 5, 6)
t2b = copy.deepcopy(t2a)

print("hash(t1a) == hash(t1b)", hash(t1a) == hash(t1b))
print("hash(t1a) == hash(t2a)", hash(t1a) == hash(t2a))
print("hash(t2a) == hash(t2b)", hash(t2a) == hash(t2b))
```

I know the answer for a smattering of 3 or 4 test-cases, but what about in general?

If you have huge tuples (say, 1 gigabyte each) will the hash values (`int`) get truncated? I could imagine that the concatenation of `x` and `y` has the same hash value as `x` if `x` is sufficiently long.

Suppose we had a million different tuples in memory. We might begin to have many different tuples associated with the same hash value.

Comment: No.  Hash codes are truncated to your machine's bit size, but the number of possible tuples is vastly greater than that.  You don't even need to introduce tuples to run into that problem - there exist distinct ints with the same hash code.

Answer (score 1):

As usual for well-formed hash functions, `a == b` implies `hash(a) == hash(b)`, but `hash(a) == hash(b)` does not necessarily imply that `a == b`.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of type, a `__hash__()` implementation is playing by the rules if `x == y` implies `hash(x) == hash(y)`. There is no reliable implication in the other direction: from `hash(x) == hash(y)`, nothing follows about how `x` compares to `y`.

This is all true even for simple types like ints. There are an unbounded number of possible Python ints, but only a finite number of possible hash codes. Therefore there *must* exist distinct ints `i` and `j` such that `hash(i) == hash(j)`.